# Deploy application on aws and make other user pay the bill

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am noob on AWS, I need to deploy an app there but I don't want to pay for it, instead the person who asked me to do the the app must be the payer, How can I do this? I saw that I can create IAM users but I don't see any documentation to delegate the payment to one IAM user and I am scared of being charged for something that I am not benefiting, I am missunderstanding the concept of IAM users? where can I find docs for achieve this purpose?

Comment: No, I asked for this in 2015 and I haven't seen anything addressing this. There's one Account tied to one Subscription. In Azure you can have multiple accounts to a subscription but AWS is one to one. Also you can't break up the bills with say a HTTP Header identifying the customer unless you implement it yourself. The common model is charging a fixed rate with various options and caps/limits.

Comment: Of other user is billable by AWS they must have an account. Add a user for you to their account?

Comment: @JeremyThompson So it is impossible to achieve this? basically I must deploy from a account that he create? how does organizations achieve this? for example when developers of a team deploy an app of  the company? also thanks for your answer

Comment: @spinkus I didn't understan you well, you mean it is possible if the person I want to be the payer has an aws account?

Comment: Organizations typically give each team an account or the entire company has multiple accounts for Dev, Test, Staging, Prod, etc.  It's not setup for customer billing, its on an Account basis. It's not going to be easy via IAM as what happens if two roles are specified then you don't know who used what. You can split up databases but running a DB per customer is expensive. To monitor the usage of the application you're going to have to do it, perhaps there's a 3rd party that offers this, if you find one please let me know.

Comment: Correction, I just learned that you can break down costs and usage data in a variety of ways, including by IAM role.  You can also set up cost allocation tags to track costs by role, and generate reports to see the breakdown of cost

Comment: @JeremyThompson so you got the answer of your 2015 question? or you mean you just can monitor the cost of each IAM user?

Comment: In AWS Cost Explorer > New Cost and Usage Report > goto Filters > LinkedAccount and filter.

Comment: Costs are owned by the account, not the IAM user, there's no real way to drill down to costs for an IAM user.  At best you can setup a new account for this customer within AWS Organizations and get cost reports for that entire account.